# How To Increase Sklearn GMM predict() Performance Speed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

I am using *Sklearn* to estimate the Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) on some data.

After the estimation, I have many query points. I would like to obtain their probabilities of belonging to each of the estimated Gaussian.

The code below works. However, the `gmm_sk.predict_proba(query_points)` part is very slow as I need to run it multiple times on 100000 sets of samples, where each sample contains 1000 points.

I guess that it happens because it is sequential. Is there a way to make it parallel? Or any other way to make it faster? Maybe on GPU using *TensorFlow*?

I saw *TensorFlow* has its own **GMM** algorithm but it was very hard to implement.

Here is the code that I have written:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
import time


n_gaussians = 1000
covariance_type = 'diag'
points = np.array(np.random.rand(10000, 3), dtype=np.float32)
query_points = np.array(np.random.rand(1000, 3), dtype=np.float32)
start = time.time()

#GMM with sklearn
gmm_sk = GaussianMixture(n_components = n_gaussians, covariance_type=covariance_type)
gmm_sk.fit(points)
mid_t = time.time()
elapsed = time.time() - start
print("learning took "+ str(elapsed))

temp = []
for i in range(2000):
    temp.append(gmm_sk.predict_proba(query_points))

end_t = time.time() - mid_t
print("predictions took " + str(end_t))
```

I solved it ! using `multiprocessing`. 
just replaced

```
temp = []
for i in range(2000):
    temp.append(gmm_sk.predict_proba(query_points))
```

with

```
import multiprocessing as mp
    query_points = query_points.tolist()
    parallel = mp.Pool()
    fv = parallel.map(par_gmm, query_points)
    parallel.close()
    parallel.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could speed up the process if you fit with the 'diagonal' or spherical covariance matrix instead of full.

Use:

`covariance_type='diag'`

or

`covariance_type='spherical'`

inside `GaussianMixture`

Also, try to **decrease** the Gaussian **components**.

However, keep in mind that this may affect the results but I cannot see other way to speed up the process.

Comment: Notice that I already use `'diag'`. It is still slow. maybe parallelize?

Comment: @itzikBenShabat the GaussianMixture function does not have a n_jobs parameter (The number of CPUs to use to do the computation) but if you find other way post it cause it will be interesting :) Also, consider doing this task using other module e.g. tensorflow or even other software like Matlab

Comment: @itzikBenShabat did you try to decrease the Gaussian components?

Comment: Its a constraint. It has to remain 1000.

Comment: @itzikBenShabat oh okay ! how long does it take to run? I am going to run it on my laptop and let you know

Comment: It takes about 4 minutes on my laptop for 2000 samples. I need to run it on 10000 samples about 200 times (=66hours just for that and there is more code).

Comment: @itzikBenShabat i understand but can't find other way using scikit-learn

Answer (score 0):

I see that your number of Gaussian components in the GMM is 1000, which, I think is a very large number, given your data dimensionality is relatively low (3). This is probably the reason that it runs slow, since it needs to evaluate 1000 separate Gaussians. If your sample count is low, then this is also very prone to overfitting. You can try a lower number of components, which will naturally be faster and will most likely generalize better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the number of Gaussians is a constraint I can't change

Comment: Then maybe you can naively parallelize over the sets of samples, run each set on a different thread for example. Of course, you need to be careful if you have to write the results into a shared container.